# mod_rewrite for complex subdomain redirects

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

These are my current directives for redirecting subdomain HTTP requests to a domain with a path.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/blog [L]
```

However, this site is a new version of a website for which social media links have been posted. These links have image URLs which are now broken since the URL now points to a different server. The images have since been migrated and the path to said images has been preserved on the new server. In light of this, I need rewrite my directives to account for these legacy links.

I need to write conditions that rewrite the URL **only** when the URL no path or when the first parameter of the URL is **not** `/wp-content/`.

I have to make conditions and rules that differentiate between these 3 URL patterns:

```
http://blog.website.com 
    -> http://website.com/blog
http://blog.website.com/wp-content/year/month/image.jpg 
    -> http://website.com/wp-content/year/month/image.jpg
http://blog.website.com/entry-url-title 
    -> http://website.com/blog/entry-url-title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ultimately how I was able to do it, with a little help from my friends, of course.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://website.com/blog [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://website.com/blog/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://website.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```